# Shell script is not able to read command line argument

Tags: shell, command, runtime-error, sh

Below is my script on which I am facing a problem while executing.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

#Parameters

Environment=$1

case ${Environment} in
   DEV) SrcFOLDER="DW17/DW_DEV"
      echo "system folder name is $SrcFOLDER"
      ;;
   SIT) SrcFOLDER="DW17/DW_SIT"
      echo "system folder name is $SrcFOLDER"
      ;;
   UAT) SrcFOLDER="DW17/DW_UAT"
      echo "system folder name is $SrcFOLDER"
      ;;
  PROD) SrcFOLDER="DW_17"
      echo "system folder name is $SrcFOLDER"
      ;;
esac

ScriptDir=/informatica/10.1.1/server/infa_shared/ExtProc
. $ScriptDir/$SrcFOLDER/SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf
```

when I ran the script `sh -c abc.sh DEV`
it threw me an error like

> /informatica/10.1.1/server/infa_shared/ExtProc//SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf:  not found

I am passing argument with script and I have limitation to use option c only.

Can you please help me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It feels like either script argument I provided is not getting read hence case statement is not able to assign any value to variable SrcFOLDER or case statement is not working at all

Comment: You are using Korn Shell .. Which has a slightly different syntax / excecution behavior.  Have you tried changing the shebang line to  straight `bash` ?  It looks like it should run as a native bash script .. `#!/usr/bin/bash` --  And excecute it `bash -c abc.sh DEV` just to test ..

Comment: still giving me same error /informatica/10.1.1/server/infa_shared/ExtProc//SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: DEV argument that I passed with script is somehow not getting processed, hence case statement is not working and my variable SrcFOLDER remained unassigned.

Comment: Take the line break out and the `.` when declaring declaring `ScriptDir` --  Make it all one line ..  `ScriptDir=/informatica/10.1.1/server/infa_shared/ExtProc/$ScriptDir/$SrcFOLDER/SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf`  Notice the double slash where it's trying to run a separated/forked  command ..

Comment: Here I am trying to execute the config file . $ScriptDir/$SrcFOLDER/SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf, also i am confused with ScriptDir=/informatica/10.1.1/server/infa_shared/ExtProc/$ScriptDir/$SrcFOLDER/SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf . can you please tell me how i can use variable without defining it, ExtProc/$ScriptDir/$ScrFOLDER ?

Comment: file SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf is present at different paths and using command like argument DEV i want to control which config file i should be using in this script. complete path for DEV version should be /informatica/10.1.1/server/infa_shared/ExtProc/DW17/DW_DEV/SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf

Comment: Why use `sh -c` at all instead of using `ksh abc.sh DEV`?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you put all arguments after `-c` in double quotes

```
~$ cat abc.sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

Environment=$1

case ${Environment} in
   DEV) SrcFOLDER="DW17/DW_DEV"
      echo "system folder name is $SrcFOLDER"
      ;;
   SIT) SrcFOLDER="DW17/DW_SIT"
      echo "system folder name is $SrcFOLDER"
      ;;
   UAT) SrcFOLDER="DW17/DW_UAT"
      echo "system folder name is $SrcFOLDER"
      ;;
  PROD) SrcFOLDER="DW_17"
      echo "system folder name is $SrcFOLDER"
      ;;
esac

ScriptDir=/informatica/10.1.1/server/infa_shared/ExtProc
. $ScriptDir/$SrcFOLDER/SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf
~$ ksh -c ./abc.sh DEV
./abc.sh[21]: .: /informatica/10.1.1/server/infa_shared/ExtProc//SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf: cannot open [No such file or directory]
~$ ksh -c "./abc.sh DEV"
system folder name is DW17/DW_DEV
./abc.sh[21]: .: /informatica/10.1.1/server/infa_shared/ExtProc/DW17/DW_DEV/SFTP_AUTOFILE.conf: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `sh -c abc.sh DEV`, a new shell is invoked which executes the script.  In that shell, `$0` is set to the string DEV, but the shell does not pass that to `abc.sh`.  It is instead calling `abc.sh` with no arguments.  You probably just want to do:

```
$ ./abc.sh DEV
```

to invoke the script from the currently executing shell, but if you want to use a new shell you could do:

```
$ sh -c 'abc.sh "$@"' sh DEV
```

The first `sh` after the command string sets `$0` for the new shell to `sh` as is typical, and then the positional arguments for the shell are set to the remaining arguments.  Those values are then passed to `abc.sh` via `"$@"`.

Note that all this requires `abc.sh` to be in a directory in your PATH, so you may need to use a full path or `./abc.sh`, as appropriate.